# Git Bash: remote: command not found

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I want to split off a folder inside my existing github repository into it's own repository so I tried following the instructions here: https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/

I've never installed git on my machine before so I downloaded the latest installer and went through the options. I choose the option 'Use Git from windows command prompt'. Once it's installed there are some commands that do not work.

Git Bash:
[image]

Git CMD:
[image]

I've tried setting the PATH variable as well manually but that doesn't fix it, I still get the same 'command not found'.

Is this a bug with the latest git? Or did I somehow mess up the install?

I'm on windows 10 machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

git is the program remote and -v are arguments for it

First you will want to clone a repository that you want for example

> git clone https://github.com/justinmeister/Mario-Level-1 mario_game

this will create a folder called mario_game with the git remote setup.

> cd mario_game
>
> git remote -v

Now you will see the remote as https://github.com/justinmeister/Mario-Level-1

Comment: See my second screenshot - it shows git remote -v as 'fatal: Not a git repository'

Comment: @Igneous01 It says that while you are in your home directory. You then tried to change into the DCS directory (using the wrong command) but didn't try to run any git commands after that. Try `cd DCS` and then `git remote -v`.